# Issue when trying to filter dictionary list using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, filter, set, list-comprehension

I want to filter from a dictionary list such as the one down below the correponding items to where`fileName` is `tree` in values of `objectAttribute` and there are not the following values: `green-field`, `snowy-field` nor `yellow-field`

```
array = [
    {'fileName': 'waterfall_074', 'objectAttribute': 'black-cliff'},
    {'fileName': 'waterfall_074', 'objectAttribute': 'waterfall'}, 
    {'fileName': 'waterfall_074', 'objectAttribute': 'black-cliff'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_test_010', 'objectAttribute': 'red-flower'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_test_010', 'objectAttribute': 'overcast-sky'}, 
    {'fileName': 'highway_bost183', 'objectAttribute': 'cloudy-sky'}, 
    {'fileName': 'highway_bost183', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'},
    {'fileName': 'highway_bost183', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'},
    {'fileName': 'highway_bost183', 'objectAttribute': 'road'},
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_076', 'objectAttribute': 'cloudy-sky'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_076', 'objectAttribute': 'yellow-field'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_092', 'objectAttribute': 'overcast-sky'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_092', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'},
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_092', 'objectAttribute': 'yellow-field'}, 
    {'fileName': 'opencountry_092', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'},
    {'fileName': 'mountain_086', 'objectAttribute': 'dusthaze-sky'},
    {'fileName': 'mountain_086', 'objectAttribute': 'rocky-mountain'},
    {'fileName': 'ibis_001', 'objectAttribute': 'black-ibis'},
    {'fileName': 'ibis_001', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'},
    {'fileName': 'ibis_001', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'},
    {'fileName': 'bison08', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'},
    {'fileName': 'bison08', 'objectAttribute': 'black-bison'},
    {'fileName': 'bison08', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'},
    {'fileName': 'volcano_0191', 'objectAttribute': 'dusthaze-sky'},
    {'fileName': 'volcano_0191', 'objectAttribute': 'rocky-mountain'}, 
    {'fileName': 'horse_097', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'},
    {'fileName': 'horse_097', 'objectAttribute': 'white-horse'},
    {'fileName': 'horse_097', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'}
]
```

From this list above there are this other list of items that there are `tree` as objectAttribute `['opencountry_092', 'horse_097', 'highway_bost183', 'bison08']`
and as you can check the only one from this list which doesn't have any of those values: `green-field`, `snowy-field` nor `yellow-field` is `highway_bost183`

I came up with the following code, however it is not working

```
def busca_images(array):
  print(array)
  arrayFiltered = [n for n in array if 'tree' in n['objectAttribute'] ]
  newSet = set()
  for e in arrayFiltered:
    newSet.add(e['fileName'])
    files = []
  for e in newSet:
    if len([n for n in array if 'green-field' in n['objectAttribute'] or 'snowy-field' in n['objectAttribute'] or 'yellow-field' in n['objectAttribute'] ]) != 0: files.append(e)
  print(list(files))
```

I believe that the error is right here in this conditional...

```
if len([n for n in array if 'green-field' in n['objectAttribute'] or 'snowy-field' in n['objectAttribute'] or 'yellow-field' in n['objectAttribute'] ]) != 0: files.append(e)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a short, reproducible example with your input, expected output, and the output you're currently getting.

Comment: Okay, @BrendanAbel... The input is the one I mentioned above while the output I am getting with my wrong code is the same for the list I get with the `tree` filter:  `['opencountry_092', 'horse_097', 'highway_bost183', 'bison08'] ` and the expected output is `'highway_bost183'`

Comment: It's really not clear what your trying to do here

Comment: @jbflow I just want to indicate which images have a `tree` but do not have any type of field (`green-field`, `snowy-field` or `yellow-field`).

Comment: "the correponding items to where fileName is tree in values of objectAttribute" Sorry, I couldn't understand this.

Comment: So, *complete wild guess here*, when you have two or more dicts that have the same `'fileName'` value, are those dicts supposed to be related to each other somehow? If so, *why not just use a single dict to represent them* (and make a list of the `objectAttributes` instead of a single item)?

Comment: "I believe that the error is right here in this conditional..." Well, it's inside a loop `for e in newSet`. Maybe it should be doing something with `e`? You would probably find it helps if you use variable names that actually reflect the intended purpose of your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def busca_images(array):
    has_tree = set()
    has_field = set()
    final = set()
    for each in array:
        if each['objectAttribute'] == 'tree':
            has_tree.add(each['fileName'])
    for each in array:
        if each['fileName'] in has_tree and each['objectAttribute'] in ['green-field', 'yellow-field', 'snowy-field']:
            has_field.add(each['fileName'])
    return list(has_tree - has_field)[0]
print(busca_images(array))
```

It's not the most elegant and there's probably a faster way of doing it without looping the list twice.

But simply:

- loop the list to find trees, add to a has_tree set
- loop again to find fields, add to has_fields set
- subtract has_field from has_tree to get value

Output: `'highway_bost183'`

Doing this has made me think. Wouldn't it be better to just have one dictionary, with the filename as the keys and then a list of attributes as the value? It would make this process alot easier.

Comment: Thank you, @jbflow, however this is not quite the result that I am trying to reach...
`'highway_bost183'` as this is the correct answer

Comment: But what about the other entries that fulfill the criteria you mention above. 

`{'fileName': 'bison08', 'objectAttribute': 'tree'}` has tree and no field?

Comment: @lucasbbs I've edited it to give that response, by adding those fileName you didn't mention to the conditional. It now returns highway_boost1283

Comment: I want to get a list of images which corresponds to such criteria... In my data sample `['opencountry_092', 'horse_097', 'highway_bost183', 'bison08']` these are the files that do have `tree` as a `objectAttribute`, but among them only 'highway_bost183' does not have none of the fields attributes...For instance in the file opencountry_092 there is the attribute green-field: {'fileName': 'opencountry_092', 'objectAttribute': 'green-field'}

Comment: OP does not want to test the *fileName* for `green-field` etc., AFAICT.

Comment: @lucasbbs OK yeah I didn't fully understand the question. I've edited the answer so that it now does what you were asking.